# bootstrap responsiveness for website

Tags: css

I have a website well ordered in the desktop size 1349x800 pixels and in mobile resolution 240x320 pixels and in 320x568 pixel but when open between 800x 768 pixels to 1180x768 pixels the elements get distorted. How to solve this issue.

Comment: use `media-query` for that

Comment: What version of bootstrap are you using? Does it contain css classes like col-*-*?

Comment: Please share your code too. It'll be helpful to solve.

Answer (score -1):

The Bootstrap grid system has four tiers of classes: xs (phones), sm (tablets), md (desktops), and lg (larger desktops). You can use nearly any combination of these classes to create more dynamic and flexible layouts.
The resolutin which you have mentioned (1180x768) falls under medium size in bootstrap grid system,to arrange your distorted content in same you need to use
bootstap grid classes for medium desktop sizes eg: col-md-4

Please visit the below link to learn more about bootstrap grid system
http://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/

Comment: it will be very kind of you down voter if you can mention the reason as well so that the same mistake can be avoided while answering in future